# Is Schopenhauer a panpsychist?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, schopenhauer

Some sources, such as Wikipedia say he is, but I have seen other people such as Bernardo Kastrup say he is pure idealist.

Comment: Why do you assume that idealism and panpsychism exclude each other?

Comment: He did not identify as either, and the labels are so vague that it is up to your taste whether to use one or both on him.